# Lot of COMMAND operation had invoked by Spring boot lettuce client to Redis cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster, lettuce

We are using lettuce redis client to connect to our redis cluster in production. We had a performance issue. while debugging we have identified that lot(almost 40K) `COMMAND` operation had invoked by few services. we couldn't able to reproduce the issue in local environment.
Can some one guide us, which component is triggering the `COMMAND` operation. The use of `COMMAND` operation

[Command Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J093o.png)

https://redis.io/commands/command

Comment: It's not any specific component rather the whole Lettuce. It's dependent on COMMAND to determine which commands are available/allowed in respective Redis instance(s).

Comment: @sazzad We are seeing too many invocation of COMMAND. Is it like for every new connection are we invoking Command Operation.
i feel that we can cache the out put of COMMAND output. As per the Lettuce Documentation we dont need any connection pooling https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#connection-pooling.is-connection-pooling-necessary

Comment: We are seeing same issue in our production environment.. Any update on this issue?